# Нажатие на кнопку в fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

При нажатии на кнопку, которая находится на фрагменте, нажатие не обрабатывается.

```
public class LoginFragment extends android.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, null);
    button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(this); // присвоение кнопки листенеру
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"2134",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Вопрос решен проблема была в этой строке

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы создаете лайаут из xml, подписываетесь на кнопку в нем, а затем создаёте новый лайаут и показываете его. Но кнопка со слушателем то в старом осталась! Возвращайте первый лайаут и будет вам счастье:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(this); // присвоение кнопки листенеру
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Плюс скорей всего используется не тот фрагмент. android.app.Fragment вместо android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: @АндроидАндроид если фрагмент показывается значит он тот. Точнее даже если компилируется.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Не могу использвать android.support.v4.app.Fragment? так как при объявлении его в FragmentTransaction он мне подчеркивает и выдаёт:
"Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.miza.prototype2.fragments.LoginFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'", а при возвращении v у меня весь фрагмент не правильно показывается...

Comment: эм, так вы в любом случае это возвращаете...

Comment: @xkor ну когда я возвращаю v, то у меня исчезает один editText и все съезжает в угол.

Comment: А вы точно делаете `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)` а не `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, null)`?